# How to wait for some text to show up in a pane

Tags: events, tmux

In a shell script, I would love to be able to send keys to a tmux session after waiting for commands to change something in a pane.

Here is one of my use cases:

```
tmux send-keys -t ...  'vi .' c-m # This opens NERDTree
sleep 3                           # Sometimes sleep 2 is not enough
tmux send-keys -t ...  c-w l      # Go to tab right
```

The commands can trigger the send key command by means of their output, but if there is a better way I would be listening.

First idea I had, and is actually ok for my simple first use case, was a clumsy

```
  function wait_for_text_event
  {
       while :; do
          tmux capture-pane -t ... -p | grep "string triggering completion" && return 0
       done
       # never executed unless a timeout mechanism is implemented
       return 1
  }
```

Now I can do

```
tmux send-keys -t ... 'vi .' c-m
wait_for_text_event 'README.md'   # meaning NERDTree has opened the split window
tmux send-keys -t ...  c-w l      # Go to tab right
```

**However**
Implementing timeouts gets already tricky in shell and the busy wait is ugly anyway.

Is there some command (or way to implement it) which would just block until some
text shows up in a pane e.g.

tmux wait-for-text -t ... "Hello World" && tmux send-keys ...

possibly with a timeout.

Or maybe I am approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: `I would love to be able to send keys to a tmux session after waiting for commands to complete` you want to wait some command to complete or wait some text in pane? they are different concept. If it's the former case, you can ask the Pid of the command instead of grepping again and again.  what's your real problem? could this be a X->Y problem?

Comment: actually it is quite simple, and I was quite imprecise.
I should have given the example.
I load vim with NERDTree and want to change to the next pane with 'c-w' l.
For that to work I need to know if nerdtree opened the pane 
I'll edit my post, thanx for the feedback

Comment: wait a moment, the "pane" you meant tmux's pane or vim's split? did you have two splits in vim?

Comment: tmux's pane in this case, I know that, once the text is in the tmux pane vim's NERDTree will have split its window

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, I think I'm looking for an answer to a similar question: If I send a command to a tmux session (e.g. `tmux send-keys -t "$window" C-z "some command" Enter`) and I don't know what the output of the sent command will be, is there a clean way to wait for the sent command to complete (before moving on to another command)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin timeout executable in linux and run a subshell. Try something like this:

```
# $1: string to grep for
# $2: timeout in s
wait_for_text_event()
{
  timeout $2 bash <<EOT
  while :; do
    sleep 1
    echo "test" | grep $1 2>&1 > /dev/null && break
  done
EOT
  echo $?
}

echo $(wait_for_text_event "text" 5)   # this times out, returncode !=0
echo $(wait_for_text_event "test" 5)   # this passes, returncode == 0
```

Comment: thx that is a nice improvement.Sorry for not accepting the answer because what I really want is a "tmux event subscription". I know I can't ask questions very well.

Answer (score 2):

`tmux capture-pane -pJ -S-10000 -t XX` will print the contents of pane XX starting from up to 10000 lines up the scrollback. So you should be able to do something like

```
until tmux capture-pane ... | grep $TEXT >/dev/null; do :; done
```

You might want to add a `sleep` not to waste CPU, and then include some amount of the scrollback in case the text appeared and scrolled away during the `sleep`.